# Creating a complex math with java script and html

Tags: javascript

I just want to know how to create a math 
with 50 input from user.

First 10 input will be added and after that it will be divided by 50%.

Example:  `10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10*0.5=answer1`

Second 10 input will be added and after that it will be divided by 25%.

Example:  `10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10*0.25=answer2`

Third 10 input will be added and after that it will be divided by 10%.

Example:  `10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10*0.5=answer3`

And final answer will be = answer1+answer2+answer3.

Comment: Why don't you give this a try and then post a sample of your code that you need help with.  Stackoverflow is really a site to help people figure out coding issues, not a site to provide the code from scratch.

Comment: I agree with @Nate, Also, it might make sense to give more context.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve